# Inconsistent visualization of numerical values in Excel 2007 vs the underlying xml file

Tags: excel, openxml, xlsx, spreadsheetml

I am attempting to read an Excel 2007 file (xlsx) from outside of Excel and I am finding an inconsistency that I cannot explain.

If you enter the value of 19.99 into a cell and then look at the underlying Xml document it is actually stored as 19.989999999999998.  This is not the only value that does this, but it is a reasonable example.  No formatting is applied in the sheet.  In my example I just open a new Workbook, type in 19.99 in A1 and save the file.

I have attempted to open this simple example in both open office and Google docs and it shows 19.99 when the document is loaded.

My question is, how do I determine when to transform this value from 19.989999999999998 into 19.99 for use in other systems?

Comment: do you need to transform this value? I mean the difference between the two is very small. Will that effect your system?

Comment: I need to have a version of the file that visually matches the content of the xlsx file.  The exact appearance matters in this case.  While the numerical "difference" is quite small and would round correctly, it is unacceptable for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variation between the 19.99 you entered and the 19.989999999999998 stored is the floating point variation... there will typically always be a slight discrepancy between the binary representation of a float (used internally by Excel) and the decimal used for display (and storage in the xlsx file).

Even if you haven't explicitly assigned a format to the cells, Excel applies a default formatting of "@" or "General", which typically (for numerics) displays to 2dp, applying scientific if needed. If you look at the number formatting for that cell (whether using theMS Excel front-end, or by examining the xlsx file), you should find that it is actually set to the default.