# Numerical values in Excel 2007 - representation vs storage in the underlying xml file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

This question is related to .NET and OpenXml.

I've already gone through the following article, it has good explanation, but not an answer to my question:
[Inconsistent visualization of numerical values in Excel 2007 vs the underlying xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859496/inconsistent-visualization-of-numerical-values-in-excel-2007-vs-the-underlying-x)

In my application, user is uploading an Excel (.xls/.xlsx) and I'm parsing using OpenXML SDK.

Parsing works fine, except a few values. Excel is storing different values than entered in some of the scenarios. Following are some examples of what user entered vs what is stored in underlying xml:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| User Entered Value | Excel Displayed Value | Stored XML Value   |
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| 4.1                | 4.1                   | 4.0999999999999996 |
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| 4.4                | 4.4                   | 4.4000000000000004 |
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
| 19.99              | 19.99                 | 19.989999999999998 |
+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+
```

My problem comes when I'm parsing this excel in .NET using OpenXML. OpenXML reads these values as what is stored as XML values. So even though user entered 4.1, OpenXML reads it as 4.0999999999999996. Now as per the one of the validations I'm running on this excel, I need to check for the decimal points. I cannot really validate what user entered in this kind of a situation.

Any help is greatly appreciated !! Since OpenXml is an SDK provided by Microsoft, I haven't tried any other Excel readers, but any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to represent data of floating point type. You can verify that by following code snippet.

Run following code,

```
string s = "4.0999999999999996";

Console.WriteLine(float.Parse(s)); 
// output 4.1

string s1 = "4.4000000000000004";

Console.WriteLine(float.Parse(s1)); 
// output 4.4

string s2 = "19.989999999999998";

Console.WriteLine(float.Parse(s2)); 
// output 19.99
```

So try to `parse` those values and you will get your expected true value as it is.